# autocomplete is not working help is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have applied this upon an input type text, but it is not working. I need some guidance to show me where I am going wrong. This is javascript code and is not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reasondescriptiontxtbox').autocomplete( {
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/getReason",
                data: "{'keywords':'" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    //alert("Error");
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

code behind:

```c#
[WebMethod]
public static IList<string> getReason(string keywords)
{
    int count = 0;
    IList<string> result = new List<string>();
    string constr 
        = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd1 = con1.CreateCommand();
    cmd1.CommandText = "select distinct Code_Description from CODE_DESCRIPTION_277 where Code_Description '%" + keywords + "%'";

    try
    {
        con1.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            count++;
            result.Add(dr["Code_Description"].ToString());

            if (count == 100)
                break;
        }

        con1.Close();

        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Will I have to add some sort of jQuery file?

Comment: What is not working? Is your web method not being called? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no i am not getting any error but the autocomplete is not functioning i dont know where is the problem thats why i have submitted whole code

Comment: does the `getReason` method being called? does it return anything other than `null`?

Comment: I would suggest you to use Firebug and reviewe all request/responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added like keyword it was also a problem and secondly i changed this:`$('#reasondescriptiontxtbox').autocomplete(` 
to this: `$('input[id$=reasondescriptiontxtbox]').autocomplete(` 
and now it is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL code appears to have a missing `like` in `where Code_Description '%" + keywords + "%'"`, could that be the cause?

You'd get no results and probably an SQL exception that is being masked by your Catch.

Try changing that line to

```
cmd1.CommandText = "select distinct Code_Description from CODE_DESCRIPTION_277 where Code_Description like '%" + keywords + "%'";
```

Comment: thanx Klors i added like keyword it was also a problem and secondly i changed this:$('#reasondescriptiontxtbox').autocomplete(                    to this: $('input[id$=reasondescriptiontxtbox]').autocomplete(                   and now it is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Master page then your javascript code should be like this
 $('#<%= textbox1.ClientID %>').autocomplete({

and make sure that you have included any version of jquery.js

Comment: thanx i changed this:  $('#reasondescriptiontxtbox').autocomplete( to this:  $('input[id$=reasondescriptiontxtbox]').autocomplete(       and now it is working perfectly fine

Comment: Hey mark this as answer so that others can also know about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would organize unit tests into your project so you can test `getReason` in isolation, with mocked input.  Then you can divide and conquer to determine where the problem is.  If the issue is on the client side, you'll need to attach a debugger to the browser and set a breakpoint in your handler(s) to inspect locals and flow of execution.